# File size in bits with ls?

Tags: linux, bash, filesize, ls

Is there a way or argument to make the bash command "ls" show the file sizes on bits?
I know that "ls -lh" shows the files with its sizes, but in bytes, kilobytes, etc.
Or any other bash command for linux that can so that?

Comment: Cross-site duplicate of http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/111049/how-does-one-find-out-how-many-bits-a-file-has-in-one-command

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This works in Linux

```
ls -l | awk '{$5=$5*8; print;}'
```

Comment: Seems to be the shortest way to do it, thanks

Comment: Here's a shorter one: `ls -l | awk '{$5=$5*8}1'`

Answer (score 1):

Write your own function, something in this direction:

```
for file in *; do
   [[ -d "$file" ]] && continue
   printf "%12u\t%s\n" "$(( $(wc -c < "$file") * 8 ))" "$file"
done
```

Comment: .. but that assumes that a byte is 8 bits.... which is not true on the univac 1108